# WEKA on Android: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=30; index=30

Tags: java, android, weka

i have a little problem with my code.

I'm using WEKA library in Android project.

I want to get data from a sqlite db.

I can't use DatabaseLoader class, so I created Instances object in this way:

```
public Instances getDatasetFromDB(String tableName, String[] select){

        Log.i(TAG, "Getting instances from Db");

        Instances result = null;
        open();

        Cursor csr = query(tableName, select, null, null, null);
        if(csr.getCount() != 0){
            Weka weka = new Weka();
            Instances centroids = weka.create_Instances("Centroids");
            List<Instance> list = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> classType = new ArrayList<>();
            while(csr.moveToNext()){
                String type = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("classType"));
                classType.add(type);
                list.add(cursorToInstance(csr));
            }
            result = new Instances(weka.addInstance(centroids, list, classType));
        }
        close();
        return result;
    }

/*Function of Weka Object*/
public Instances create_Instances(String name){
        FastVector wekaAttributes = new FastVector();

        for (int i = 0; i<ApplicationProperties.getnFeature(); i++)
            wekaAttributes.addElement(new Attribute(GenericUtils.typeData(i)));

        Instances dataSet = new Instances(name, wekaAttributes, 0);

        int n_activity = ApplicationProperties.getnActivity();
        FastVector classNominal = new FastVector(n_activity);
        for (int i=0; i<n_activity; i++){
            classNominal.addElement(GenericUtils.idToActivity(i));
        }
        dataSet.insertAttributeAt(new Attribute("classType", classNominal), dataSet.numAttributes());

        dataSet.setClassIndex(dataSet.numAttributes() - 1);

        return dataSet;
    }

public Instances addInstance(Instances instances, List<Instance> list, List<String> type){
        Iterator<Instance> i = list.iterator();
        Iterator<String> j = type.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext() && j.hasNext()){
            Instance inst = i.next();
            inst.setDataset(instances);
            double[] tmp = inst.toDoubleArray();

            String t = j.next();
            tmp[tmp.length-1] = GenericUtils.activityToId(t);

            instances.add(new Instance(1.0, tmp));
        }
        return instances;
    }
```

This code returns this:

```
@relation Centroids

@attribute acc_max_x numeric
@attribute acc_min_x numeric
@attribute acc_mean_x numeric
@attribute acc_std_x numeric
@attribute acc_rms_x numeric
@attribute acc_max_y numeric
@attribute acc_min_y numeric
@attribute acc_mean_y numeric
@attribute acc_std_y numeric
@attribute acc_rms_y numeric
@attribute acc_max_z numeric
@attribute acc_min_z numeric
@attribute acc_mean_z numeric
@attribute acc_std_z numeric
@attribute acc_rms_z numeric
@attribute gyro_max_x numeric
@attribute gyro_min_x numeric
@attribute gyro_mean_x numeric
@attribute gyro_std_x numeric
@attribute gyro_rms_x numeric
@attribute gyro_max_y numeric
@attribute gyro_min_y numeric
@attribute gyro_mean_y numeric
@attribute gyro_std_y numeric
@attribute gyro_rms_y numeric
@attribute gyro_max_z numeric
@attribute gyro_min_z numeric
@attribute gyro_mean_z numeric
@attribute gyro_std_z numeric
@attribute gyro_rms_z numeric
@attribute classType {Fermo,Cammino,Corro,Veicolo}

@data
0.020366,-0.049443,9.699037,0.011994,0.020186,0.050924,-0.010524,0.035161,0.012316,0.038155,9.739549,9.656769,0,9.715311,9.699051,0.078441,-0.078495,0.000719,0.02763,0.027849,0.024923,-0.026115,-0.000634,0.009217,0.009327,0.023255,-0.020865,0,0.007926,0
0.839357,-0.582571,9.413732,0.264762,0.923015,-0.825299,-1.967114,-1.385451,0.210502,1.658316,10.171442,8.569599,0,9.459311,9.443481,0.564504,-0.654348,0.000326,0.123502,0.136114,0.707076,-0.658781,0.00107,0.134813,0.137025,0.628173,-0.686233,0,0.113967,1
0.994211,-0.382427,6.74315,0.325523,0.683864,7.406008,6.538764,6.994379,0.1867,7.035604,7.668721,5.612368,0,6.779348,6.768002,0.11319,-0.174827,0.000703,0.019038,0.030755,0.482416,-0.118256,0.004761,0.038078,0.040536,0.315722,-0.143182,0,0.03144,2
0.60635,-1.418608,9.763421,0.315172,0.320185,0.627898,-0.514171,-0.040041,0.201248,0.20899,9.885362,9.643541,0,9.779818,9.763464,6.832833,0,-0.02351,0.395488,0.396995,4.230241,-0.002749,0.014193,0.244926,0.244967,0.000917,-5.28093,0,0.312452,3
...
...
```

The problem is when the code arrives to this point:

```
Instances data  = new Instances(database.getDatasetFromDB(TrainingSetModel.TBL_NAME,  TrainingSetModel.COLUMNS_DATASET ));
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes()-1);
ibk.buildClassifier(data);
```

This is the stack trace:

```
W/System.err: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=30; index=30
W/System.err:     at weka.core.Instance.isMissing(Instance.java:395)
W/System.err:     at weka.core.Instance.classIsMissing(Instance.java:221)
W/System.err:     at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1132)
W/System.err:     at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1023)
W/System.err:     at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1302)
W/System.err:     at weka.classifiers.lazy.IBk.buildClassifier(IBk.java:487)
W/System.err:     at com.unipa.uniar.classification.Knn.getInstances(Knn.java:36)
W/System.err:     at com.unipa.uniar.classification.Knn.<init>(Knn.java:26)
W/System.err:     at com.unipa.uniar.classification.ClassificationTask.doInBackground(ClassificationTask.java:54)
W/System.err:     at com.unipa.uniar.classification.ClassificationTask.doInBackground(ClassificationTask.java:19)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

I don't understand what is the problem of my code.

The Instances object has 31 attributes [0-30], i don't understand why limit is 30.

**UPDATE:**

I test if there are missing value adding this code:

```
private void getInstances() throws Exception {
        UniAR_DBAdapter database = new UniAR_DBAdapter(context);
        data  = new Instances(database.getDatasetFromDB(TrainingSetModel.TBL_NAME,  TrainingSetModel.COLUMNS_DATASET ));
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes()-1);
        for (int i=0; i<data.numInstances(); i++){
            for (int j=0; j < data.numAttributes()-1; j++){
                if(data.instance(i).isMissing(j)) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Instance: " + String.valueOf(i) + "Attribute: " + String.valueOf(j) + "Missing");
                    data.instance(i).setClassMissing();
                }
            }
        }
        ibk.buildClassifier(data);
    }
```

No log was printed. So, there are no missing attributes.

Comment: It doesn't.  It has 30 attributes, 0-29.  30 is out of bounds.  That's what it means when it says length:30

Comment: I know it means "length: 30". If you count the number of attributes it is 31 including the class attribute. Why do you say that are 30 [0-29]? Am I wrong in counting?

Answer (score 0):

From the log seems you have some value not set or missing. you should use

```
data.setClassMissing();
```

set the instances class value to missing.

Comment: I add code to check all attributes  and to find if some values are not set or missing. There are no missing value.